# Java UI, trying to go to next page upon clicking button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a simple GUI with 3 radio buttons and a button.  I want the user to select a radio option, then upon clicking the button the user will be directed to a different Java UI depending upon which radio button they selected.  Here is my method:

```
 private void btnContinueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {
      if(rbCSV.isSelected())
      {

      }
      else if(rbExcel.isSelected())
      {

      }
      else if(rbDatabase.isSelected())
      {

      }
      else
      {

      }
 }
```

I am new to Java Swing, and not sure of the syntax that will allow me to direct the user to the next page.  Sort of like a Wizard, I guess.  Any help would be awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some dedicated wizard library would be helpful, e.g. http://code.google.com/p/cjwizard/

Comment: What do you mean by "page"? Are you using JPanels? You can swap JPanels to implement the kind of behaviour you are describing.

Comment: @Brandon, See edit. It includes an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: @miku that project has a new URL now: https://github.com/creswick/cjwizard

Comment: Wizard?  Better switch to Microsoft for that.  Or learn how to code Swing properly.

Answer (score 6):

Recommendations:

1. Read the [How to Use Radio Buttons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) tutorial
2. Read the [How to Use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) tutorial
3. Learn how to use a [`ButtonGroup`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html), since you'll only want one button to be selected at a time

---

```
public final class RadioButtonDemo {
    private static CardPanel cards;
    private static Card cardOne;
    private static Card cardTwo;
    private static Card cardThree;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("RB Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(
                new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        cards = new CardPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(cards);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ControlPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void createCards(){
        cardOne = new Card(
                "Card 1", 
                new JLabel("This is card one"), 
                Color.PINK);
        cardTwo = new Card(
                "Card 2", 
                new JLabel("This is card two"), 
                Color.YELLOW);
        cardThree = new Card(
                "Card 3", 
                new JLabel("This is card three"), 
                Color.CYAN);
    }

    private static final class Card extends JPanel{
        private final String name;

        public Card(
                final String name, 
                final JComponent component, 
                final Color c){
            super();
            this.name = name;
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            setBackground(c);
            add(component);
        }

        public final String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    }

    private static final class CardPanel extends JPanel{
        public CardPanel(){
            super(new CardLayout());
            createCards();
            add(cardOne, cardOne.getName());
            add(cardTwo, cardTwo.getName());
            add(cardThree, cardThree.getName());
        }
    }

    private static final class ControlPanel extends JPanel{
        private static JRadioButton showCardOneButton;
        private static JRadioButton showCardTwoButton;
        private static JRadioButton showCardThreeButton;
        private static JButton showButton;

        public ControlPanel(){
            super();
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            add(createJRadioButtonPanel());
            add(createJButtonPanel());
        }

        private final JPanel createJRadioButtonPanel(){
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            showCardOneButton = new JRadioButton(cardOne.getName());
            showCardOneButton.setSelected(true);
            showCardTwoButton = new JRadioButton(cardTwo.getName());
            showCardThreeButton = new JRadioButton(cardThree.getName());
            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            group.add(showCardOneButton);
            group.add(showCardTwoButton);
            group.add(showCardThreeButton);
            panel.add(showCardOneButton);
            panel.add(showCardTwoButton);
            panel.add(showCardThreeButton);

            return panel;
        }

        private final JPanel createJButtonPanel(){
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            showButton = new JButton("Show");
            showButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
                    if(showCardOneButton.isSelected()){
                        cl.show(cards, showCardOneButton.getText());
                    }
                    else if(showCardTwoButton.isSelected()){
                        cl.show(cards, showCardTwoButton.getText());
                    }
                    else if(showCardThreeButton.isSelected()){
                        cl.show(cards, showCardThreeButton.getText());
                    }
                }
            });
            panel.add(showButton);

            return panel;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is too much.  If you look at my logic, I have if a radio button is selected when the button is clicked then do what is in the brackets.  What I want to do in the brackets is just go to another JPanel, which I plan on making a separate class.

Comment: @Brandon, A majority of this code is just filler. If you look at the crux of it, it focuses on using `CardLayout` to exchange panels based on the currently selected `JRadioButton`. That's all. If there's already a layout manager that possesses such logic, why not make use of it?

Answer (score 2):

```
JPanel panelCSV, panelExcel, panelDatabase;
CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
JPanel pagePanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
pagePanel.add(panelCSV, "CSV");
pagePanel.add(panelExcel, "Excel");
pagePanel.add(panelDatabase, "Database");

public void btnContinueActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ( rbCSV.isSelected() ) {
        cardLayout.show(pagePanel, "CSV");
    } else if ( rbExcel.isSelected() ) {
        cardLayout.show(pagePanel, "Excel");
    } else if ( rbDatabase.isSelected() ) {
        cardLayout.show(pagePanel, "Database");
    } else {
        // ....
    }
}
```