# Java - Repaint Not Working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, applet, repaint

So I am making a Text-Based RPG Applet in Java. I am using SWING panels, with text fields and buttons on it. I am programming it in Netbeans, and I am using the GUI editor. I have crafted the HTML page and it opens in the browser fine. When I click a button to switch panels (basically set the first the non-visible), the new panel doesn't load. I tried using repaint() and validate() but it just doesn't work..... Any help?

```
package applettest;

import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class NewApplet extends java.applet.Applet {

    startScreen ss;
    registerScreen rs;
    charactercreationScreen ccs;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        try {
            //This sets the look and feel to NIMBUS.
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                    startup();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   

    public void startup() {
        showCharacterCreationScreenSTART();
        showRegisterScreenSTART();
        showStartScreenSTART();
    }

    public void showStartScreen() {
        setSize(410, 350);
        ss = new applettest.startScreen(this);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(ss, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(ss, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
    }

    public void showStartScreenSTART() {
        setSize(410, 350);
        rs.setVisible(false);
        ss = new applettest.startScreen(this);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(ss, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(ss, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        repaint();
        validate();
    }

    public void showRegisterScreen() {
        repaint();
        validate();
        ss.setVisible(false);
        setSize(400, 350);
        rs = new applettest.registerScreen(this);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(rs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(rs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        repaint();
        validate();
    }

    public void showRegisterScreenSTART() {
        repaint();
        validate();
        ccs.setVisible(false);
        setSize(400, 350);
        rs = new applettest.registerScreen(this);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(rs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(rs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        repaint();
        validate();
    }

    public void showCharacterCreationScreen() {
        rs.setVisible(false);
        setSize(400, 350);
        ccs = new applettest.charactercreationScreen(this);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(ccs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(ccs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        repaint();
        validate();

    }

    public void showCharacterCreationScreenSTART() {
        setSize(400, 350);
        ccs = new applettest.charactercreationScreen(this);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(ccs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(ccs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));

    }
}
```

Comment: repaint works fine, but you've got a bug in your program -- where? who the heck knows since we don't see any code!

Comment: The code shown doesn't show much related to your problem -- except that you are using NetBeans to create your Swing GUI code -- something I recommend you don't do as it can shield you from having to learn Swing and thereby interfere with your understanding what you're doing and not doing. Better to go through the Swing tutorials and learn Swing right.

Comment: In each method you can see I use repaint() and validate. Let me try and edit some more, ill see if I can edit in a few minutes.

Comment: I see a ton of nearly impossible to decipher Matisse-generated code. I see methods where you may be adding component(s) to this GUI but don't seem to be removing all components. But mainly I see a debugging nightmare.

Comment: Rule #1 for Netbeans GUI designer: do not use `GroupLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

See also:

- [How to Use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [Java UI, trying to go to next page upon clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034176/java-ui-trying-to-go-to-next-page-upon-clicking-button/7034449#7034449)
- [Dynamically Add Components to a JDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988317/dynamically-add-components-to-a-jdialog/6988341#6988341)

Comment: Code is there as requested... I don't really know how to add all the panels at once..

Comment: @Justin, If you want any sort of robustness in your Swing application, I suggest you move away from NetBeans and actually do the coding yourself. Automating this process via a GUI builder will only hurt you.

Comment: I know this, but this is a start for me. I just needed something to generate code so I don't have to type out like 213497084721384 lines just for 1 panel.

Comment: 1+ for suggesting CardLayout ;)

Comment: @Justin: while NetBeans generates 100000 lines, we can write it in a few easy to understand lines, and  you can too.  I strongly urge  you to move away from NetBeans-generated code. Use it as an IDE, fine as it's an excellent one, but don't let its drag-and-drop utility hinder your education.

Comment: Alright, I will try to do that. No one has ever explained that to. So yeah, I guess I will just use CardLayout!

Answer (score 2):

> I tried using repaint() and validate() but it just doesn't work

FYI, when using Swing it should be:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

although that code is generally used when adding/removing individual components from a panel. If you are swapping entire panels then CardLayout is the way to go.

Also, you should be extending JApplet, NOT Applet.

Comment: Thanks a ton! But when I extend JApplet, I get errors!
`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1242)
 at applettest.NewApplet.init(NewApplet.java:22)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`